# Scraping table data from websites

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've written a script in vba to parse table from any website if the html elements are not encrypted in javascript. There is a table index in my script in which inputting the right number it is possible to parse any preferable table. Any input on this will be highly appreciated.

```
Sub GetTabularContent()
    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object
    Dim S$, R&, C&

    With New ServerXMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("table")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```